# Unable to get data using BulkRead method of EFCore.BulkExtensions

Tags: entity-framework-core, bulk, .net-core-3.1, webapi, efcore.bulkextensions

Hope you are doing well.

I'm using EFCore.BulkExtensions[3.1.6] in .Net Core 3.1 Web API to perform bulk operations. Bulk insert and update are working fine but I'm not able to use BulkRead method to get the bulk data.

I refer this link https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions#read-example and tried it but I'm not getting data. Maybe I didn't understand the example.

Here is the code which I've tried:

```
    IList<VehicleSubModel> submodels = new List<VehicleSubModel>(); // VehicleSubModel is the domain Entity

        var result = submodels.Select(s => new VehicleSubModel() { Id = s.Id, Name = s.Name }).ToList();
        var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig { UpdateByProperties = new List<string> { nameof(VehicleSubModel.Id), nameof(VehicleSubModel.Name) } };

        await Task.Run(() => Context.BulkRead(result, bulkConfig));
```

I want to get Id and Name of all VehicleSubModel but it's not returning any record. Could anyone please explain how we can use the BulkRead method of EFCore.BulkExtensions. I spend several hours to get it done, search many links but not getting its solution.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: bulkconfig should have a property for refetching updated data from database, i dont remtmber the name of it

Comment: @OğuzhanKahyaoğlu do you mean setOutputIdentity?

Comment: @timdowd yes that was the name of option

Comment: This comment looks like it could be of interest. https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/issues/733#issuecomment-1017417579 However, I am still having a hard time understanding the whole thing. I can't find a single working example anywhere.